# GMP library in one file

Tags: c++, include, numbers, gmp

I have a simple question.
How can I make a program that can operate on huge float numbers without external libraries?
I got the idea to actually throw a whole library into my source code.
I found this: https://github.com/panks/BigInteger/blob/master/BigIntegerSingleFile.cpp
However when I'm dividing simple numbers like 20/12 it's always giving me "0".
So I decided to use GMP instead of BigInt but I have no idea how to include it in my code without using #include statement. My code needs to use only standard libraries.

Comment: The requirement that you can use third-party libraries only by throwing them into your source code is most peculiar. But I don't think there's any particular reason you can't grab the GMP source, process the part(s) you need with `gcc -E` to do preprocessing only, and dump the result into your project. There will no doubt be some complexities to work through, though, which I'm too lazy to do, which is why this isn't an answer...

Comment: Is that the scent of someone side-stepping the intended objective of homework that I smell?

Comment: See mini-gmp: https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/6af90241df51/mini-gmp/README